# In Spanish, is it possible to make 'principal' or 'gradual' an adverb without adding "-mente" at the end?

Tags: adverbios

In Spanish, is it possible to make 'principal' or 'gradual' an adverb without adding *-mente* at the end?

Comment: I'm just curious. Why are you asking this?. Anyway instead of *principalmente* you can use **máxime** but I don't know any word for _gradualmente_ without "-mente"

Comment: @DGaleano - because when you are learning a language you are interested in trying out this and that, in order to find patterns and rules, which you can then apply, to make many new permutations of words.

Comment: @aparente001 your guess makes sens but let´s wait for the op comment

Comment: I'd like to know as well. I'm reminded of how German for the most part (I think) doesn't have a specific adverb-forming suffix; most adjectives work as adverbs directly. Not the case in Spanish, in general.

Comment: @DGaleano - Sorry for the misunderstanding, I've deleted my obsolete comments.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to turn adjectives into adverbs without adding *-mente* is to replace the suffix with its actual meaning, which is "de manera" (or "de modo" or "de forma").

So if you don't want to say "gradual*mente*", you can say "*de manera* gradual". Same for "*de modo* principal" for "principal*mente*"; "*de forma* lenta" instead of "lenta*mente*", etc. It's like saying "*in a* slow *manner*" instead of "slow*ly*" in English.

Of course, you can also use synonym expressions like "poco a poco" instead of "gradualmente", "sobre todo" in place of "principalmente" and the like.

Comment: Great answer.  I think the point you made in the last paragraph is the take-home message.  I suggest you add usage notes along these lines: In casual conversation, we'll almost always use these alternate expressions; in formal writing, the *-mente* adverbs would be more likely.  Also: "de modo" is especially useful if the *-mente* form sounds awkward, such as with *cruel*.  E.g., I hear "de modo cruel" rather than "cruelmente". (If you agree, that is.)

Answer (score 3):

Some adjectives can be adverbialized with what today we might call the zero or null suffix, as in *rápido*.  But there is a very small, basically fixed number of these, all of which were inherited through Latin's neuter-adjective-as-adverb formation.  But neither *principal* nor *gradual* are a part of this special group of adjective-adverbs, and therefore must use *-mente* or other adverbializing structures (such as *de forma X*, *de modo X*, *en plan X*, etc.)

Comment: Also helpful.  Now I wonder if there's some simple pattern that governs membership in that class?

Answer (score 2):

My feeling from reading recent Spanish texts is that the structure "de manera" (or "de forma")+ adjective is used more and more commonly and tends to replace almost completely adjectives ending in -mente. Check this text from a report, where this structure is used 3 times:

> "Las necesidades y oportunidades medioambientales son abordadas de manera favorable respondiendo de manera directa a la necesidad del país de reducir la contaminación fortaleciendo los sistemas de tratamiento de aguas residuales. De igual manera, se busca promover un uso más eficiente del agua."

I wonder whether any of you have also observed this tendency.